# Filter array based on value in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that I want to filter based on whether or not a nested array contains a certain value.

**Data**

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "text" : "#number# Tips to Get #solution#",
      "types" : [ "email"]
    },
    {
      "text" : "Want #desiredResult#? Use #productName#",
      "types" : [ "ad", "email" ]
    },
    {
      "text" : "Your Search For #solution# Ends Here",
      "types" : [ "ad", "email" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to return a new array based on whether a specific value is present. E.g. if I were to filter by `ad`, only the last 2 entries would be returned:

**Filtered by `ad`**

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "text" : "Want #desiredResult#? Use #productName#",
      "types" : [ "ad", "email" ]
    },
    {
      "text" : "Your Search For #solution# Ends Here",
      "types" : [ "ad", "email" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I initially thought I could use `Array.prototype.filter()`, but I haven't been able to get that to work. Which I assume is because the array is nested, but I'm unsure on how to reach it.

How would I filter to return only those entries where the type matches a filtered value?

Comment: Show us what you tried that you were not able to get working.

Comment: Don't use the `json` tag (or term) for JavaScript object literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in order to achieve what you are looking for.

```js
let data = {
  "content": [
    {
      "text" : "#number# Tips to Get #solution#",
      "types" : [ "email"]
    },
    {
      "text" : "Want #desiredResult#? Use #productName#",
      "types" : [ "ad", "email" ]
    },
    {
      "text" : "Your Search For #solution# Ends Here",
      "types" : [ "ad", "email" ]
    }
  ]
}

const filterByType = (data, filterBy) => {
  return (data || []).filter(d => {
    return d.types.some(type => type === filterBy)
  })
}

console.log(filterByType(data.content, "ad"))
```

Or [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) with `Array.filter` will also work. You can refer below for the same

```js
let data = {
  "content": [{
      "text": "#number# Tips to Get #solution#",
      "types": ["email"]
    },
    {
      "text": "Want #desiredResult#? Use #productName#",
      "types": ["ad", "email"]
    },
    {
      "text": "Your Search For #solution# Ends Here",
      "types": ["ad", "email"]
    }
  ]
}

const filterByType = (data, filterBy) => {
  return (data || []).filter(d => {
    return d.types.includes(filterBy)
  })
}

console.log(filterByType(data.content, "ad"))
```

Comment: instead of ```some``` I'd use ```indexOf```, but that's a good solution

Comment: Yes @LuísMestre that also works absolutely fine. But instead of again having a condition to check `!== -1` I preferred something which by default provide a boolean value.